# some Java threads seems stuck in Android if opening many of them

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my Android APP, I have to open lots of (more than 100) threads and make them keep running. Every thread represents a separated business.  Every thread is bond with a message looper and message handler.

I have a socket to receive datas from server and send the data to the corresponding thread by its message handler. However, I found that after running about 10 hours, some threads' handler can't get data anymore and the others still work.

The memory and CPU taken by the APP seems normal. The UI thread is working fine. New thread can be created and run. The problem only happened in some old threads.

Anybody know what happened? If Android's JVM can't maintain so many threads?

Comment: are you using `HandlerThread`s? or call `Looper.prepare` / `Looper.loop` manually?

Comment: You can customize `ThreadPoolExecutor` to maintain all of your threads if any gets lost or dead.

Comment: @pskink I use Looper.prepare and Looper.loop in the thread

Comment: tried to diagnoze your `Looper` / `Handler` with `Looper#dump()` / `Handler#dump()` methods (or `Looper#setMessageLogging()`) ?

Comment: Thanks @pskink. We found some logic problem when using Looper.dump().

Comment: so what was it?